# Biblatex - Using data annotations to format the date

Tags: biblatex

It is common in references to indicate an attributed field by putting it into brackets. If a book comes with no date printed, but we happen to know the date (so it is not "uncertain", nor "circa"), we can indicate that by putting the date within brackets.

I'd like to do that with biblatex's data annotation feature.

I've tried to do so using `\DeclareFieldFormat{date}` (there is a `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}` in `biblatex.def` suggesting this as a possibility), but the conditionals for annotations are not recognized within this scope, even though it is a formatting directive. How then could I use the data annotation to put a date into brackets?

I know I could always use `year = {[1933]},`. But the question here is how to do so with biblatex's data annotation facilities (thus keeping biblatex's advanced date features).

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{gillies,
  author       = {Gillies, Alexander},
  title        = {Herder and the Preparation of {Goethe's} Idea of World Literature},
  journaltitle = {Publications of the English Goethe Society},
  date         = {1933},
  date+an      = {=attributed},
  series       = {newseries},
  volume       = {9},
  volume+an    = {=attributed},
  pages        = {46-67},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% This works, but affects all dates
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labeldate}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

% This doesn't work, for the conditional is not recognized
%\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\iffieldannotation{attributed}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}{#1}}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{labeldate}{\iffieldannotation{attributed}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}{#1}}

% It works with the conditional for volume, for example
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\iffieldannotation{attributed}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\autocite{gillies}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date` fields are a bit special. Within `\DeclateFieldFormat{date}` `biblatex` does not know which date field it is processing (that is because the date is not printed via `\printfield{date}` and indeed for `biblatex` there is no field `date` at all, the field format `date` is just used with `\printtext`), so you can't use `\iffieldannotation` because that command relies on detecting the field currently being processed. `biblatex` also needs to resolve `labeldate` which adds another layer of complexity.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{gillies,
  author       = {Gillies, Alexander},
  title        = {Herder and the Preparation of {Goethe's} Idea of World Literature},
  journaltitle = {Publications of the English Goethe Society},
  date         = {1933},
  date+an      = {=attributed},
  series       = {newseries},
  volume       = {9},
  pages        = {46-67},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ifdateannotation}[2]{%
  \def\blx@tempa{#1}%
  \ifcsundef{abx@field@\blx@tempa source}
    {}%
    {\letcs\blx@tempa{abx@field@\blx@tempa source}%
     \edef\blx@tempa{\blx@tempa date}}%
  \ifinlistcs{#2}{abx@annotation@field@\blx@tempa}}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\ifdateannotation{date}{attributed}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labeldate}{\ifdateannotation{labeldate}{attributed}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\autocite{gillies}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: moewe, Wow!! I've spent several hours yesterday digging the code trying to figure a point of entrance to do this. And I didn't get even close! Thank you very very much!

Comment: moewe, would you mind if I made a feature request out of this one? I do think it deserves.

Comment: @gusbrs Sure, go ahead and open a feature request if you think it can be useful.